# Friend functions - Declaration Order

Tags: c++, header-files, friend-function

I have two classes called `Screen` and  `Window_mgr`.

`Screen` is allowing `Window_mgr` to modify its private / protected members via the friend function declaration.

As a result `Window_mgr` defines at the very end of the code a non-member function called `Window_mgr::clear` which is supposed to make use of it.

Unfortnately, I get some ridiculous errors which I can't explain myself.

What am I missing?

[image]

### Screen.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef SCREEN_H
#define SCREEN_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Window_mgr {
public:
    // location ID for each screen on the window
    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    // reset the Screen at the given position to all blanks
    void clear(ScreenIndex);
private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens{ Screen(24, 80, ' ') };
};

class Screen {

public:

    // Friends
    friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);
    //friend class Window_mgr;

    // Fields
    // typedef => creates an alias
    // typedef std::string::size_type pos;
    // alternative way to declare a type member using a type alias
    using pos = std::string::size_type;

    // Constructors
    Screen() = default; // needed because Screen has another constructor
                        // cursor initialized to 0 by its in-class initializer
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) {} // get the character at the cursor
    Screen &display(std::ostream &os) // function is in the class body => implicitly inline
    {
        do_display(os);
        return *this;
    }
    const Screen &display(std::ostream &os) const // function is in the class body => implicitly inline
    {
        do_display(os);
        return *this;
    }

    // Methods
    char get() const { return contents[cursor]; } // implicitly inline
    inline char get(pos ht, pos wd) const; // explicitly inline
    Screen &move(pos r, pos c); // can be made inline later
    Screen &set(char);
    Screen &set(pos, pos, char);

private:
    // Fields
    mutable size_t access_ctr;
    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    std::string contents;

    // Methods
    void do_display(std::ostream &os) const { os << contents; }
};

inline Screen &Screen::set(char c)
{
    contents[cursor] = c; // set the new value at the current cursor location
    return *this; // return this object as an lvalue
}

inline Screen &Screen::set(pos r, pos col, char ch)
{
    contents[r*width + col] = ch; // set specified location to given value
    return *this; // return this object as an lvalue
}

// we can specify inline on the definition
inline Screen &Screen::move(pos r, pos c) {
    pos row = r * width; // compute the row location
    cursor = row + c; // move cursor to the column within that row
    return *this; // return this object as an lvalue
}

char Screen::get(pos r, pos c) const // declared as inline in the class
{
    pos row = r * width; // compute row location
    return contents[row + c]; // return character at the given column
}

void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
    // s is a reference to the Screen we want to clear
    Screen &s = screens[i];
    // reset the contents of that Screen to all blanks
    s.contents = string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}

#endif
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `#include <vector>` and `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: sorry forgot to copy the most recent version of it, even with including the vector, I still get the error message regarding "Screen: undeclared identifier" and so on.

Comment: I've added a `class Screen;` for the declaration of `Screen` to the top of the file but that doesn't solve it entirely.

Comment: `class Screen;` at the top would solve it if you wanted to do `vector<Screen*>`, but for `vector<Screen>` the complete `Screen` must be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot declare a vector of `Screen` objects inside your `Window_mgr` class, because `Screen` is not known to the compiler at that point in your code. If you were to declare a vector of pointers, you could fix it by forward-declaring `Screen`, but for a vector of actual objects full definition must be available.

You need to switch around the order of `Window_mgr` and `Screen`, and declare friendship to `Window_mgr` class:

```
class Screen {
public:
    friend class Window_mgr;
    ...
};
class Window_mgr {
public:
    // location ID for each screen on the window
    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    // reset the Screen at the given position to all blanks
    void clear(ScreenIndex);
private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens{ Screen(24, 80, ' ') };
};
```

> why does the compiler know `Window_mgr` but not `Window_mgr::ScreenIndex`

C++ has a special rule for class names used in friendship declarations:

> If the name of the class that is used in the friend declaration is not yet declared, it is forward declared on the spot.

That is how the compiler "knows" of `Window_mgr` (i.e. it does not; it takes your word for it). There is no such rule for member functions or member types declared inside "befriended" classes. That is why the compiler does not know about `Window_mgr::ScreenIndex`.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer - that was one of the solution I've eventually found. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);` instead of `friend class Window_mgr;` - this because the friend function declaration it self refers to `ScreenIndex` of `Window_mgr` - Any idea how this cross-reference can be avoided?

Comment: yes, still the same error. Anyway, I thought there would be an easy solution to this. Although I still can't quite comprehend why there is no problem with `friend class Window_mgr` but with `friend void Window_mgr::clear(Window_mgr::ScreenIndex);`. Both refer to `Window_mgr` or one of its members which shouldn't be known to the compiler at this point.

Comment: @HansMusterWhatElse in order to forward declare a function the compiler needs to have a definition for the types of the parameters, at the time you forward declare Window_mgr::clear(Window_mgr::ScreenIndex) the compiler doesn't know what Window_mgr::ScreenIndex is, you are deferring the definition of Window_mgr until after Screen is defined.

Comment: So why does the compiler know `Window_mgr` but not `Window_mgr::ScreenIndex`? Bases on the knowledge that it works perfectly fine with `friend class Window_mgr;`

Comment: @HansMusterWhatElse Please see the edit for the explanation of this difference.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using "friend" for this.. just add a clear() public member function to class Screen, and call it from the window manager

```
// declaration
Screen &clear();

// definition
inline Screen &Screen::clear() {
    contents.resize(height * width, ' ');
    return *this; // return this object as an lvalue
}

// use
void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
    // s is a reference to the Screen we want to clear
    Screen &s = screens[i];
    // reset the contents of that Screen to all blanks
    s.clear();
}
```

See it live in [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6d90b2889837a72)